# Raspberry pi terminal keeps saying there's a syntax error only to point at "Python 3.5.3" at the top of my shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I recently got a raspberry pi and have been trying to run python code off of it. However, whenever I attempt to do so in the terminal, the following error pops up:

> ---
>
> File "Python-3.6.5/rc_car.py", line 1
>       Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
>                ^
>
> ### SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The file that I'm trying to run is called `rc_car.py`.  I've updated my raspberry pi to python v3.6, so I don't think that my system is out of date. Also, I made sure that there is only one file named `rc_car.py` in my memory, so I don't think that's it either.
Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Here's the code if it helps at all (I included the shell, since that seems to be where the error is at):

```py
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO as io
io.setmode(io.BCM)
import sys, tty, termios, time

# These two blocks of code configure the PWM settings for
# the two DC motors on the RC car. It defines the two GPIO
# pins used for the input, starts the PWM and sets the
# motors' speed to 0
motor1_in1_pin = 4
motor1_in2_pin = 17
io.setup(motor1_in1_pin, io.OUT)
io.setup(motor1_in2_pin, io.OUT)
motor1 = io.PWM(4,100)
motor1.start(0)
motor1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

motor2_in1_pin = 24
motor2_in2_pin = 25
io.setup(motor2_in1_pin, io.OUT)
io.setup(motor2_in2_pin, io.OUT)
motor2 = io.PWM(4,100)
motor2.start(0)
motor2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

# Defining the GPIO pins that will be used for the LEDs on
# the RC car and setting the output to false
io.setup(18, io.OUT)
io.output(18, False)

io.setup(23, io.OUT)
io.output(23, False)

# The getch method can determine which key has been pressed
# by the user on the keyboard by accessing the system files
# It will then return the pressed key as a variable
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch

# This section of code defines the methods used to determine
# whether a motor needs to spin forward or backwards. The
# different directions are acheived by setting one of the
# GPIO pins to true and the other to false. If the status of
# both pins match, the motor will not turn.
def motor1_forward():
    io.output(motor1_in1_pin, True)
    io.output(motor1_in2_pin, False)

def motor1_reverse():
    io.output(motor1_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor1_in2_pin, True)

def motor2_forward():
    io.output(motor2_in1_pin, True)
    io.output(motor2_in2_pin, False)

def motor2_reverse():
    io.output(motor2_in1_pin, False)
    io.output(motor2_in2_pin, True)

# This method will toggle the lights on/off when the user
# presses a particular key. It will then change the status
# of the lights so it will know whether to turn them on or
# off when it is next called.
def toggleLights():

    global lightStatus

    if(lightStatus == False):
        io.output(18, True)
        io.output(23, True)
        lightStatus = True
    else:
        io.output(18, False)
        io.output(23, False)
        lightStatus = False

# This method will toggle the direction of the steering
# motor. The method will determine whether the user wants
# to turn left or right depending on the key they press and
# then make the appropriate adjustment. It works as a toggle
# because the program cannot read multiple pressed keys at
# the same time. The possible positions of the wheels are
# "right", "centre" and "left". It will then update the
# status of the wheel to access next time it is called.
def toggleSteering(direction):

    global wheelStatus

    if(direction == "right"):
        if(wheelStatus == "centre"):
            motor1_forward()
            motor1.ChangeDutyCycle(99)
            wheelStatus = "right"
        elif(wheelStatus == "left"):
            motor1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
            wheelStatus = "centre"

    if(direction == "left"):
        if(wheelStatus == "centre"):
            motor1_reverse()
            motor1.ChangeDutyCycle(99)
            wheelStatus = "left"
        elif(wheelStatus == "right"):
            motor1.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
            wheelStatus = "centre"

# Setting the PWM pins to false so the motors will not move
# until the user presses the first key
io.output(motor1_in1_pin, False)
io.output(motor1_in2_pin, False)
io.output(motor2_in1_pin, False)
io.output(motor2_in2_pin, False)

# Global variables for the status of the lights and steering
lightStatus = False
wheelStatus = "centre"

# Instructions for when the user has an interface
print("w/s: acceleration")
print("a/d: steering")
print("l: lights")
print("x: exit")

# Infinite loop that will not end until the user presses the
# exit key
while True:
    # Keyboard character retrieval method is called and saved
    # into variable
    char = getch()

    # The car will drive forward when the "w" key is pressed
    if(char == "w"):
        motor2_forward()
        motor2.ChangeDutyCycle(99)

    # The car will reverse when the "s" key is pressed
    if(char == "s"):
        motor2_reverse()
        motor2.ChangeDutyCycle(99)

    # The "a" key will toggle the steering left
    if(char == "a"):
        toggleSteering("left")

    # The "d" key will toggle the steering right
    if(char == "d"):
        toggleSteering("right")

    # The "l" key will toggle the LEDs on/off
    if(char == "l"):
        toggleLights()

    # The "x" key will break the loop and exit the program
    if(char == "x"):
        print("Program Ended")
        break

    # At the end of each loop the acceleration motor will stop
    # and wait for its next command
    motor2.ChangeDutyCycle(0)

    # The keyboard character variable will be set to blank, ready
    # to save the next key that is pressed
    char = ""

# Program will cease all GPIO activity before terminating
io.cleanup()
[DEBUG ON]
>>> 
[DEBUG OFF]
>>>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Hello, I hope you were able to solve your problem. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please upvote it, and consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you copy-pasted the entirety of an interactive session as a Python script. You must remove parts in the beginning and the end of the file:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>
```

```
[DEBUG ON]
>>> 
[DEBUG OFF]
>>>
```

These parts are not valid Python code because they are simply prompts from the interactive Python shell. If you copied this from a blog or a website, they did not indicate clearly that it was not a Python file "as-is", but the transcript of an interactive Python shell.

Comment: Also, it is common practice to begin a Python script with the line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` The actual line depends on your distribution.